# MDX Sorting: Show Name Of Day but sort by order of days

Tags: sql, sorting, ssas, mdx

I am new to MDX and I am struggling with ordering/sorting.  I am looking to compare sales by the day of the week (Sun, Mon, Tue...)  I have a calendar dimension set up based on a day by day table which joins to (I am using SQL verbiage, not familiar with MDX verbiage just yet) the measurements cube by a date key.   For each date key I have a column for what day, what name of day, # of the day (1-7), month #, Week#, Month Name, etc.

I want to display the Name of the day, but sort by the # of the day.

I have tried numerous iterations, but here is the simple query I am working with:

```
SELECT
{
  NONEMPTY([CAL Calendar].[Month Name].Members)
} ON COLUMNS,
{
  ORDER({NONEMPTY([CAL Calendar].[Week Day Name].Members)}, [CAL Calendar].[Week Day].CurrentMember.Member_Name, BDESC)
} ON ROWS
FROM [DEVICE_FACTS]
WHERE ([CAL Calendar].[Cal Date Key].[20140101]:[CAL Calendar].[Cal Date Key].[20140615], [Measures].[Widget_New % (Of AllWidgets)])
```

I get an error

```
"The MDX Function CURRENTMEMBER failed because the coordinate for the "Week Day" attribute contains a set."
```

I know that the error is coming from the second parameter of the `ORDER()` function, `[CAL Calendar].[Week Day]`.  The query will only process results if the second parameter is from the same field as the first parameter.  But I don't want to sort by the `NAME` of the week, I want to sort by the order of the days in the week.

Comment: Can you make changes to the cube, or are you only writing queries? It would be nice to update the cube to use the day # to sort that attribute.

Comment: Yes, I can make any changes.  At this time, it's 1) My first cube, and 2) I am the only one using it.  I have reviewed the attributes for my [CAL Calendar] dimension, but I didn't see any properties that I could change for sorting.  I also looked up sorting by attributes but I only find articles that relate to the ORDER() function.  If you could point me towards a tutorial, article, or share the correct terminology I should search for I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Can you tell me the version and type of SSAS db you are using? Ex: SQL Server 2012 Multidimensional, Enterprise

Comment: If it is multidimensional, you have a couple of choices.  http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1743/ssas-%E2%80%93-using-dimension-orderby-attributekey or http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3228/change-sort-options-on-dimension-attributes-in-sql-server-analysis-services/

Comment: I am currently using 2008R2.  These examples are exactly what I need.  Thank you for all your time!

Comment: The answer provided by mmarie in the comments section of my question helped with my issue. I was not sure how else to mark this question as answered. Thank you mmarie!

Comment: You can put the contents of what mmarie said here as an answer, or you can leave a comment on your question to @mmarie to add the comments as an answer... but posting an "answer" that says a comment fixed your issue is not the way to do it. Comments are volatile and can be deleted/removed with no trace.

Comment: @mmarie - From UncleJasper75's "answer" below, it appears you got the answer right in one of your comments. You should probably post/expand on your answer

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause accepts only a tuple. A Tuple is a cell of the cube, meaning, it's given by specifying 1 and only 1 member in each dimension (if no member is specified, the "All" member is assumed).

In your query, you try to slice by a set, which is a range of dates. The way to do it is to first define a member, based on an Aggregation of that set, and then using that new member on the tuple:

```
WITH MEMBER [CAL Calendar].[Current Period] as Aggregate([CAL Calendar].[Cal Date Key].[20140101]:[CAL Calendar].[Cal Date Key].[20140615] )
SELECT
{
  NONEMPTY([CAL Calendar].[Month Name].Members)
} ON COLUMNS,
{
  ORDER({NONEMPTY([CAL Calendar].[Week Day Name].Members)}, [CAL Calendar].[Week Day].CurrentMember.Member_Name, BDESC)
} ON ROWS
FROM [DEVICE_FACTS]
WHERE ([CAL Calendar].[Current Period], [Measures].[Widget_New % (Of AllWidgets)])
```

Comment: sousa, you can have sets in a where clause in MDX

Answer (score 0):

This is a change you should make in the SSAS multidimensional model. You have two choices:

- Change the key column on the week day name dimension attribute to be the weekday number, and make weekday name the name and sort by the key.  [Detailed instructions are here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3228/change-sort-options-on-dimension-attributes-in-sql-server-analysis-services/).
- Change the orderbyattribute property on the weekday name dimension attribute to weekday number. [Detailed instructions are here.](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1743/ssas-%E2%80%93-using-dimension-orderby-attributekey)